# Python: How to exclude a group of characters before a specific character in a fixed string

Tags: python, regex, string, character

Using a python script I want to exclude all characters at and before the '@' from the userlist*. I only want to see the full domain names.
I have tried achieving this using regex, replace, substrings, custom functions etc... but nothing is generating the output I need.
I feel like I'm looking In the wrong direction and I must be missing something simple.

***Userlist:**

```
user@domain.com
anotheruser@somedomain.org
superuser@domains.co.uk
foo@domain.com
```

Comment: Yes, you might consider `split()`.

Comment: How would I be using split? In conjunction with substrings? The userlist is generated in my script like this: `domain = temp[1].split()[0].strip()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
email = 'user@domain.com'
_, domain = email.split('@')
print domain

>>> domain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is (a) solution using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re    
>>> re.search(r'(?<=@).*', 'me@example.com').group()
'example.com'
```

Comment: @py_newby: It's probably a good idea to check for a match first, before calling `group()`. If your input contains a badly formed email, `"me&#64;example.com"`, say, then the `re.search()` will return `None`. Of course calling `None.group()` will give you an error ;)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to split() you can slice the index as follows

```
email = 'user@domain.com'
domain = email[email.index['@']+1:]
print domain

>>> domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly safer version of @chishaku's answer; it returns everything following the first occurrence of the target character or substring, and will not choke on 0 or multiple occurrences.

```
def after_first(ch, s):
    return s.split(ch, 1)[-1]

for user in userlist:
    print after_first("@", user)
```